# How to make a PictureBox move using arrow/WASD keys?

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I'm trying to use this code to make a pong game, but for what ever reason, my code isn't working. As far as I can tell, everything should be correct.

I have the Timer enabled and the code compiles, because the program boots without errors, but the PictureBoxes aren't moving.

Can someone spot my issue?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool P1Up, P1Down, P2Up, P2Down;

    int Speed = 12;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MoveTriggerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (P1Up == true) Player1Paddle.Top += Speed;
        if (P1Down == true) Player1Paddle.Top -= Speed;
        if (P2Up == true) Player2Paddle.Top += Speed;
        if (P2Down == true) Player2Paddle.Top -= Speed;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int P1Y = Player1Paddle.Location.Y;
        int P2Y = Player2Paddle.Location.Y;
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "w") P1Up = true;
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "s") P1Down = true;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) P2Up = true;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) P2Down = true;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int P1Y = Player1Paddle.Location.Y;
        int P2Y = Player2Paddle.Location.Y;
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "w") P1Up = false;
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "s") P1Down = false;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) P2Up = false;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) P2Down = false;
    }
}
```

Footnote: Wanted to get paddle movement implemented before looking at adding the ball or score.

Comment: e.KeyCode.ToString() does not do what you think it does.  Prefer Keys.W and Keys.S

Comment: What's the point of declaring and assigning two unused variables in the KeyUp / KeyDown handlers ? `int P1Y = Player1Paddle.Location.Y; int P2Y = Player2Paddle.Location.Y;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "w")
```

should be

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
```

and so on.

It's in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode?view=net-5.0)).

Also check that MoveTriggerTick is correctly registered as  timer handler.

Comment: Ok, having dome some (likely) jank testing, I now know that the issue is in fact the timer. I've done some digging and changed the timer part of the code to add this;

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer move = new Timer();
            move.Interval = 20;
            move.Tick += new EventHandler(MoveTriggerTick);
            move.Start();
        }`

But I still have no movement. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You need to use basic debugging tools, this we can't do it instead of you.

Use breakpoints in each function to execute line by line the code, and check if the variables are set as you imagine, and if the conditional instruction are hit. Alternatively, you can also put some `Console.WriteLine("Some debug message")` everywhere and inspect the console, especially in the if (turn the `if (condition_xyz) instruction;` into `if(condition_xyz) { Console.WriteLine("The condition xyz is true!"); instruction; }`). Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/